# Maven - ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependencies

Can someone please explain what this error is and when it occurs?

```
Downloading: file://C:/.../org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-1.4.0.RELEASE.pom
Exception in thread "pool-11-thread-1" ---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.2/java/maven/lib/aether-api-1.13.1.jar
constituent[1]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.2/java/maven
constituent[18]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.2/java/maven/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.2/java/maven/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jarjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.resolveDestinationPath(FileWagon.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.resourceExists(FileWagon.java:265)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:577)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 7 more
```

Why maven can not find `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`. Looking into local repository I'm able to find `org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-providers\2.7\...` and `org\apache\commons\parent\...`, `org\apache\commons\lang\...`, `org\apache\commons\exec\...`, `org\apache\commons\compress\...`, `org\apache\commons\pool2\...`. I can not figure out when this problem occurs, so I'm not able to resolve this problem...

Comment: your classpath is broken try to rebuild the project and maven update

Comment: Have you tried to clean your local repo?

Comment: Delete .m2, restart computer -> same problem

Comment: what is your POM file?

Comment: Is your M2_HOME pointing to the same location as the Maven executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed! I have downloaded manually maven 3.5 under https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and copied file `commons-lang3-3.5.jar` to `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\lib\`. I'm using NetBeans 8.2 with Maven as Plug-In.

Comment: please keep in mind that `commons-lang` is a dependency of your application, not of maven embedded in NetBeans. It will work, but will you always drop all dependencies to `NetBeans\maven\lib` when you need to build something? It will quickly become unruly. Fixing your maven settings and/or pom file for the project should be your solution.

Comment: Why do u think, I need to drop all deps from my application to `NetBeans\maven\lib`. This is not correct. Here are all deps for maven placed. So there is no need to add used deps to build projects into it.

Comment: I did not say to drop all your deps into `NetBeans\maven\lib` - quite the opposite. What I said was that it is your application dependency and should be put in the `<dependencies>` of your application in the pom file ,as per answer below.

Comment: This is even my opinion. I'm doing nothing else. But for some reason maven is using common-lang internal. Including it to the application pom's does not resolve my problem. Edit: commons-lang is used internal and it is in my case not a dep from my application.

Comment: Not sure what @diginoise is hating on.  I just encountered this exception using Netbeans 8.2 and the bundled maven that comes with it. Copying commons-lang2.6.jar to C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\lib\ fixed it for me.

Comment: @Ryan what I meant is that you cannot keep dropping all your project dependencies into maven's lib folder, as you will soon end up with a world of trouble (like 2 versions of the same dependency, loading order etc). Maven is built to manage these problems, you just have to use it right.

Comment: @diginoise I don't depend on commons-lang2.6.  Look at the stacktrace - the exception is coming out of the maven process itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```